# Help to figure out xinput transform matrix for a tablet?

Tags: xinput, tablet, wacom, 3d

I have a small wacom pad and a large monitor. And i wanted to reduce the area of the screen where the tablet surface is mapped. Sadly graphical utility does not allow this.
Currently the configuration is the following:

```
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (216): 0.571429, 0.000000, 0.428571, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
```

This maps to the HDMI connected 2nd monitor in landscape mode. I want to rotate mapping 90 degrees and use half of the screen in portrait mode. Infotunnely just multiplying given figures to rotation matrix gives total mess. As i unerstand due to not square shape of the area. But no idea how to do it right. So basically i need do the following.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured out. Basic transform matrix can be

```
0.25  0.000000  0.75 0.000000  1.000000  0.000000 0.000000  0.000000  1.000000
```

Pretty good starting point.